# Twists of cubic threefolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Let k be a field of characteristic $0$.

> > Let $X$ be a variety over k which is isomorphic to a smooth cubic threefold over $\bar{k}$. Then is $X$ isomorphic to a smooth cubic threefold over $k$?

For motivation, let's consider some other cases.

- For cubic curves, the analogous question has a a negative answer in general, as elliptic curves can have quite complicated twists.
- For cubic surfaces however the answer is yes. This is because cubic surfaces are embedded by the anticanonical divisor, which is already defined over $k$.

This latter argument does not work however for cubic threefolds, as for a cubic threefold, the hyperplane section is half the anticanonical divisor. So the question is whether the anticanonical divisor is always divisible by $2$ in the Picard group of $X$.

Note that the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence yields the exact sequence
$$0 \to \mathrm{Pic}(X) \to \mathrm{Pic}(X_\bar{k})^{\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{k}/k)}=\mathbb{Z} \to \mathrm{Br}(k),$$
so the obstruction to $X$ being isomorphic to a cubic threefold over $k$ is given by an element of $\mathrm{Br}(k)[2]$.

Comment: Just a comment, which I'm sure you already know: the case of plane conics is very similar, and in that case the obstruction class in $\mathrm{Br}(k)$ is given by the conic itself (as Severi-Brauer variety).  So I would wonder whether there is a natural way to associate a Brauer class to a smooth cubic threefold.

Comment: The Brauer class in question is that of the Severi-Brauer variety parametrising effective divisors in the class $-K_X/2$ (see e.g. Serre, *Local Fields*, X.6).  Looking at the case of a smooth cubic threefold, it seems to have dimension 4, since then it's just the dual of the ambient $(\mathbf{P}^4)$.

Comment: Also, the answer is yes if *X* has a *k*-rational point, or if *k* is a number field and *X* has points everywhere locally.  None of this helps very much though.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the comments. I was not aware of the nice geometric interpretation of the associated Brauer class, thanks. If you have any further ideas on this problem, please do let me know.

Comment: @MartinBright doesn't your description of the S-B variety answer the question with "Yes, the Brauer obstruction is trivial because a twist of ${\bf P}^4$ is in ${\rm Br}[5]$, and thus trivial if it's also 2-torsion"?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies I think it does, and ut shows more generally that a variety that over $\overline{k}$ is a smooth degree $d$ hypersurface in $\mathbb P^{n}$ is also such a hypersurface over $k$ as long as $d$ is relatively prime to $n+1$ and $n \geq 43$.

Comment: Where does $n \geq 43$ come from?  That condition certainly doesn't hold here.  Nor, for that matter, for an elliptic curve, with $n = 2$; how does a curve such as $y^2 + x^4 + 1 = 0$ over $\bf R$ escape this argument?

Comment: @Martin/Noam: Thanks to both of you! If one of your would like to post this as an answer, then I will accept it.

Comment: I think Will meant to say that $n \geq 4$. In this case the Lefschetz hyperplane section theorem tells you that the Picard group of such a hypersurface is cyclic and generated by the hyperplane class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out by Noam Elkies, my comment above can be turned into a positive answer to the question.

In the exact sequence

> $\DeclareMathOperator{\Pic}{Pic}\DeclareMathOperator{\Br}{Br}0 \to \Pic X \to (\Pic \bar{X})^{G_k} \to \Br k$,

the arrow $\delta \colon (\Pic \bar{X})^{G_k} \to \Br k$ sends the class of an effective Cartier divisor $D$ to the class of the Severi--Brauer variety whose $\bar{k}$-points are isomorphic to the projectivisation of $\mathrm{H}^0(\bar{X},\mathcal{O}(-D))$.  See Serre, *Local Fields*, X.6 for a passing mention of this fact, and Grothendieck, *Le groupe de Brauer, III*, 5.4 for more details (though he doesn't actually prove it, saying "on (plus précisément, J. Giraud) vérifie que la classe de cet élément dans $\Br(Y)$ est bien $\delta(\xi)$.")

In the particular example here, $\Pic X$ is of index $2$ in $(\Pic \bar{X})^{G_k}$, so the image of $\delta$ is killed by $2$.  On the other hand, taking $D=-K_X/2$, the vector space $\mathrm{H}^0(\bar{X},\mathcal{O}(-D))$ has dimension $5$, since we are assuming that $\bar{X}$ is isomorphic to a cubic threefold, on which $D$ is the class of a hyperplane section.  It follows (for example Serre, *loc. cit.*) that $\delta(D) \in \Br k$ is killed by $5$.  So $\delta(D)=0$, and $D$ lies in $\Pic X$.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above the obstruction is given by some $A \in Br(k)[2]$, and this obstruction vanishes if $X$ has a $k$-rational point. Since $X$ has a rational point over some odd degree extension, $A$ must become trivial over an odd degree extension. This means that $A$ is already trivial over $k$.

Comment: I agree that a cubic threefold over $k$ has a point over some odd degree extension. But why does a twisted cubic threefold have such a point? Is there a natural odd degree morphism to projective $3$-space?